# How to remove the extension of a file?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cygwin

I have a folder that is full of .bak files and some other files also. I need to remove the extension of all .bak files in that folder. How do I make a command which will accept a folder name and then remove the extension of all .bak files in that folder ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To remove a string from the end of a BASH variable, use the `${var%ending}` syntax. It's one of [a number of string manipulations available to you in BASH](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Use it like this:

```
# Run in the same directory as the files
for FILENAME in *.bak; do mv "$FILENAME" "${FILENAME%.bak}"; done
```

That works nicely as a one-liner, but you could also wrap it as a script to work in an arbitrary directory:

```
# If we're passed a parameter, cd into that directory. Otherwise, do nothing.
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
  cd "$1"
fi
for FILENAME in *.bak; do mv "$FILENAME" "${FILENAME%.bak}"; done
```

Note that while quoting your variables is almost always a good practice, the `for FILENAME in *.bak` is still dangerous if any of your filenames might contain spaces. Read *David W.*'s answer for a more-robust solution, and [this document](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html) for alternative solutions.

Comment: What if there's a space in the file name?

Comment: Thanks. this works well. Can I make this command do the task for any directory ? I don't want to cd into the directory all the time.

Comment: Script updated to handle spaces (quotes in BASH still allow variable substitution) and to cd into a directory. As listed [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html), `do` and `done` are the way to declare the beginning and end of a `for` or `while` loop in BASH.

Comment: +1, although the only substantial difference between our solutions is my use of the `-f` argument.

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways to remove file suffixes:

In BASH and Kornshell, you can use the environment variable *filtering*. Search for `${parameter%word}` in the BASH [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for complete information. Basically, `#` is a *left filter* and `%` is a *right* filter. You can remember this because `#` is to the left of `%`.

If you use a double filter (i.e. `##` or `%%`, you are trying to filter on the biggest match. If you have a single filter (i.e. `#` or `%`, you are trying to filter on the smallest match.

What matches is *filtered* out and you get the rest of the string:

```
file="this/is/my/file/name.txt"
echo ${file#*/}   #Matches is "this/` and will print out "is/my/file/name.txt"
echo ${file##*/}  #Matches "this/is/my/file/" and will print out "name.txt"
echo ${file%/*}   #Matches "/name.txt" and will print out "/this/is/my/file"
echo ${file%%/*}  #Matches "/is/my/file/name.txt" and will print out "this"
```

Notice this is a *glob* match and not a regular expression match!. If you want to remove a file suffix:

```
file_sans_ext=${file%.*}
```

The `.*` will match on the period and all characters after it. Since it is a single `%`, it will match on the smallest *glob* on the right side of the string. If the filter can't match anything, it the same as your original string.

You can verify a file suffix with something like this:

```
if [ "${file}" != "${file%.bak}" ]
then
    echo "$file is a type '.bak' file"
else
    echo "$file is not a type '.bak' file"
fi
```

Or you could do this:

```
file_suffix=$(file##*.}
echo "My file is a file '.$file_suffix'"
```

Note that this will remove the period of the file extension.

Next, we will loop:

```
find . -name "*.bak" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
    echo "mv '$file' '${file%.bak}'"
done | tee find.out
```

The `find` command finds the files you specify. The `-print0` separates out the names of the files with a NUL symbol -- which is one of the few characters not allowed in a file name. The `-d $`\0`means that your input separators are NUL symbols. See how nicely the`find -print0`and`read -d $'\0'` together?

You should almost never use the `for file in $(*.bak)` method. This will fail if the files have any white space in the name.

Notice that this command doesn't actually move any files. Instead, it produces a `find.out` file with a list of all the file renames. You should always do something like this when you do commands that operate on massive amounts of files just to be sure everything is fine.

Once you've determined that all the commands in `find.out` are correct, you can run it like a shell script:

```
$ bash find.out
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation and especially for the `find.out` technique. That's a really good way to sanity-check before doing something potentially ugly to your file system.

Answer (score 2):

`rename .bak '' *.bak`

(`rename` is in the `util-linux` package)

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: there is no error checking:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$1"
for i in *.bak ; do mv -f "$i" "${i%%.bak}" ; done
```

Comment: your script did not work and is also hanging my directory structure.

Comment: @bashboy: Perhaps spaces in your file names? I modified the script to try to account for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the find command to get all the subdirectories

```
for FILENAME in `find . -name "*.bak"`; do mv --force "$FILENAME" "${FILENAME%.bak}"; done
```